# Read txt via nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a txt file as attached.

```
1000,name,surname,CheckIn,19.01.2023 20:18
1002,name,surname,CheckIn,19.01.2023 20:18
1000,name,surname,CheckOut,19.01.2023 20:18
```

[screenshot of the text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOz8e.png)
I want to extract it like this;

> [{"id":"1000","checkIn":"19.01.2023 10:07:00"}, {"id":"1000","checkOut":"19.01.2023 10:07"}
> {"id":"1000","checkIn":"19.01.2023 10:07"}, {"id":"1000","checkOut":"19.01.2023 10:07"}]

i didn't do that anyone can help me ?

i did try before
read file
split with \n
I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: I would help you, but you added the file content as an image and I can't copy it

Comment: Thank you, Take it 1000,name,surname,CheckIn,19.01.2023 20:18
1002,name,surname,CheckIn,19.01.2023 20:18
1000,name,surname,CheckOut,19.01.2023 20:18

Answer (score 0):

Loading file:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'

const file = readFileSync('filename.txt')
```

Parsing:

```js
const file = `1000,name,surname,CheckIn,19.01.2023 20:18
1002,name,surname,CheckIn,19.01.2023 20:18
1000,name,surname,CheckOut,19.01.2023 20:18`

const result = file.split('\n').map(line => {
  const [id, name, surname, type, time] = line.split(',')
  return {
    id,
    [type]: time
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: can we update this code to delete blank lines? I'm sorry I made you tired :(